# Google table Chart : how do I change the row background color based on a column value

Tags: google-visualization

I am using google table chart to show some data as a table. Based on the status value on the row, I have to change the background color of the row. So I have to show multiple colors dynamically. I have checked the table chart documentation and also searched online. But could not find such a functionality provided. Please help.

Answer (score 12):

Here are some options for you...

1. Use the [ColorFormat formatter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#colorformat)
2. Add your own `html` in the data by providing

   > `v:` value
   >   `f:` formatted value
   >   and
   >   `allowHtml: true` [configuration option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#configuration-options)
3. Modify the table yourself on the `'ready'` event

see following example which uses all three...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Department');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Revenues');
    data.addRows([
      ['Shoes', 10700],
      ['Sports', -15400],
      ['Toys', 12500],
      ['Electronics', -2100],
      ['Food', 22600],
      ['Art', 1100],
      [
        // add you own html
        {v: 'Web', f: '<div style="background-color: cyan;">Web</div>'},
        {v: 9999, f: '<div style="background-color: cyan;">9999</div>'}
      ]
    ]);

    var container = document.getElementById('table_div');
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(container);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        if (data.getValue(i, 1) === 1100) {
          // modify the table directly on 'ready'
          container.getElementsByTagName('TR')[i+1].style.backgroundColor = 'magenta';
        }
      }
    });

    // use formatter
    var formatter = new google.visualization.ColorFormat();
    formatter.addRange(-20000, 0, 'white', 'orange');
    formatter.addRange(20000, null, 'red', '#33ff33');
    formatter.format(data, 1); // Apply formatter to second column

    table.draw(data, {
      allowHtml: true
    });
  },
  packages: ['table']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: see this answer for more options --> [Use Google Visualiztion Formatter on Rows rather than Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56262894/5090771)

Answer (score 0):

When mixing *HTML DOM* with *data object* the rowIndex could be out of sync and edit the wrong row. In my case I used `dashboard()` and  `bind()` with `ChartWrapper()` & `ControlWrapper()` to use `StringFilter`, so I avoided `addListener()` to change *HTML DOM* and rather modified *data object* before rendering:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
  if (data.getValue(i, 1) === 1100) {
    // change entire row
    data.setRowProperty(i, 'style', 'background-color:magenta;');
    // or change columns 0 & 1
    data.setProperty(i, 0, 'style', 'background-color:magenta;');
    data.setProperty(i, 1, 'style', 'background-color:magenta;');
  }
}
```