# Google Charts dashboard using Google Sheet

Tags: google-visualization

I'm having trouble with developing a Google Charts Dashboard using a Google Sheet. The only examples I'm able to find are ones like the below where you have to manually create the data. Is anyone able to show me how to achieve the below using data from a Google Sheet?

Thanks in advance

```
    <html> <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the controls package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['controls']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates a dashboard, a range slider and a pie chart,
      // passes in the data and draws it.
      function drawDashboard() {

        // Create our data table.
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Name', 'Donuts eaten'],
          ['Michael' , 5],
          ['Elisa', 7],
          ['Robert', 3],
          ['John', 2],
          ['Jessica', 6],
          ['Aaron', 1],
          ['Margareth', 8]
        ]);

        // Create a dashboard.
        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
            document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

        // Create a range slider, passing some options
        var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
          'containerId': 'filter_div',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Donuts eaten'
          }
        });

        // Create a pie chart, passing some options
        var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'PieChart',
          'containerId': 'chart_div',
          'options': {
            'width': 300,
            'height': 300,
            'pieSliceText': 'value',
            'legend': 'right'
          }
        });

        // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'pieChart',
        // so that the pie chart will only display entries that are let through
        // given the chosen slider range.
        dashboard.bind(donutRangeSlider, pieChart);

        // Draw the dashboard.
        dashboard.draw(data);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the dashboard-->
    <div id="dashboard_div">
      <!--Divs that will hold each control and chart-->
      <div id="filter_div"></div>
      <div id="chart_div"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37115872/5090771) should get you close...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks WhiteHat

I found a solution:

```
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', {'packages':['controls','linechart']});
  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
function initialize() {
  // Replace the data source URL on next line with your data source URL.
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kHnIbV5ZLjmcFXRfGx8hHVkLoYzYMMJlV3lk4Cr-R7I/edit?usp=sharing');


  // Send the query with a callback function.
  query.send(drawDashboard);
}

function drawDashboard(response) {
  var data = response.getDataTable();
  // Everything is loaded. Assemble your dashboard...
  var namePicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'filter_div',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnLabel': 'Name',
      'ui': {
        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': false    
      }
    }
  });
  var laptimeChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'LineChart',
    'containerId': 'chart_div'
  });

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div')).
    bind(namePicker, laptimeChart).
    draw(data)

}
```

Comment: Took me a bit that you actually need to merge this piece of code with the one above, but it finally works! :)