# Populating a Google Charts Dashboard with an external Google Sheet

Tags: google-visualization

I just got finished implementing the [solution from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37237366/google-charts-dashboard-using-google-sheet) on a similar topic, but the solution is not working for me.

I'm trying to create a dashboard that uses data from a google spreadsheet but I can't seem to get it to load correctly.

I routinely get the following error message whenever I load the web page:

```
One or more participants failed to draw()
```

Here's the code I'm using right now:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Visualization API and the controls package.
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'controls']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

  function initialize() {
      var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FnETUo8yrthFBdUYsQ8Ty9e8pK3ouWZntvDnXlhHKws/edit#gid=0');
      query.send(drawDashboard)
  }

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates a dashboard, a range slider and a pie chart,
  // passes in the data and draws it.
  function drawDashboard(response) {

    // Create our data table.
    var data = response.getDataTable();

    // Create a dashboard.
    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
        document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

    // Create a range slider, passing some options
    var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
      'containerId': 'filter_div',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'Donuts eaten'
      }
    });

    // Create a pie chart, passing some options
    var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'PieChart',
      'containerId': 'chart_div',
      'options': {
        'width': 300,
        'height': 300,
        'pieSliceText': 'value',
        'legend': 'right'
      }
    });

    // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'pieChart',
    // so that the pie chart will only display entries that are let through
    // given the chosen slider range.
    dashboard.bind(donutRangeSlider, pieChart);

    // Draw the dashboard.
    dashboard.draw(data);
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="dashboard_div">
        <!--Divs that will hold each control and chart-->
            <div id="filter_div"></div>
            <div id="chart_div"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Link to the spreadsheet can be seen here:  [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FnETUo8yrthFBdUYsQ8Ty9e8pK3ouWZntvDnXlhHKws/edit#gid=420659822](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FnETUo8yrthFBdUYsQ8Ty9e8pK3ouWZntvDnXlhHKws/edit#gid=0)

The dashboard I'm trying  to draw is taken directly from the source documentation listed here:  https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls

I'm trying to follow the example about loading external spreadsheets here:  https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets

The link to the working file I'm using for this project can be seen here:  https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/example-server/index.html

I've tried removing all header links and styling in the previous link to verify nothing else was interfering with the visualization API and this did not solve the problem either.

Also:

- Privacy for the spreadsheet is set to 'Public on the web'
- The link being used in the query is taken directly from the address bar, but I also used the 'sharing link' provided by google when you prompt for it.
- I'm using data that's exactly the same as the examples in the google documentation to make implementation as easily as possible.

**Edit**

Due to an answerer's prompt, I experiemented with different modifications of my query URL, which so far have not worked.

Here's the URL in my address bar:

**URL**

[image: URL for Google Sheet]

It's a single sheet document.

In response to the first answer, I've tried the following query URL's, but without success.

**First:**

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FnETUo8yrthFBdUYsQ8Ty9e8pK3ouWZntvDnXlhHKws/gviz/tq?sheet=Sheet1
```

**Second:**

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FnETUo8yrthFBdUYsQ8Ty9e8pK3ouWZntvDnXlhHKws/gviz/tq?gid=0
```

**Third:**

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FnETUo8yrthFBdUYsQ8Ty9e8pK3ouWZntvDnXlhHKws/gviz/tq?gid=1FnETUo8yrthFBdUYsQ8Ty9e8pK3ouWZntvDnXlhHKws
```

The idea behind this last URL is that in the new google sheets the gid is the string after d/ and before /edit.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Find your `dataSourceURL` at:

> `var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FnETUo8yrthFBdUYsQ8Ty9e8pK3ouWZntvDnXlhHKws/edit#gid=0');`

Replace:

> `edit#gid=0`

with:

> `gviz/tq?sheet=Sheet1`

If that doesn't work, then you'll need to use the `gid` which is a unique 9 to 10 digit number. (ex. `gid=1104711743`). Open your sheet and look at the address bar, you should see it at the end of the url.

Your line should look like this:

> `var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FnETUo8yrthFBdUYsQ8Ty9e8pK3ouWZntvDnXlhHKws/gviz/tq?gid=1234567890');`

Comment: thank you for this answer.  However, I tried your URL suggestions and they did not work for me.  I updated the question to reflect these attempts.  Question:  is it possible that working locally would affect this at all?  I recall having a similar issue with google charts a while back where it didn't work when I viewed the page locally but loaded when I put it on a server.

Comment: Okay, thank you.  So on a hunch I duplicated the sheet to create the 10 digit  gid number to use the URL format that you used and it still didn't work.  Then I changed the privacy settings on my spreadsheet from 'Anyone With the Link Can View' to 'Public On The Web' and that didn't work either.  Do you have any idea if there are some settings on my spreadsheet which might prevent this data from populating?

Comment: @JonathanBechtel There's only one more thing I think might work, notice that my sheet has multiple sheets, add a sheet to it and see if it will reveal it's gid.

Comment: I already tried that.  Here's a link to the URL in the sheet:  http://imgur.com/9KzIvvk.  Here's a link to the uploaded file I'm working with:  https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/example-server/index.html.  I also tried changing https to http but this did not work either.  I've tried stripping out the hotlinks to the bootstrap files but that had no effect either. My apologies if this question is more than you bargained for!