# Use Google Visualiztion Formatter on Rows rather than Columns

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Google Visualization's formatter can be called on a specific column, but not on a particular row.

I want to color code by the row, where each entry per row has a specific condition to meet. How can I achieve that?

> Call formatter.format(table, colIndex), passing in the DataTable and the >(zero-based) column number of the data to reformat.

[Link to Docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#formatters)

Comment: check this answer --> [Google table Chart : how do I change the row background color based on a value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36949638/5090771)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Seems like the best option for me was manually wrapping the cell in a div when I populate the data with a for loop. But for that cyan example, there's an unwanted border around the cell, which I can't figure out how to avoid. Alternatively, I'm trying to achieve the same result with the setcell, any ideas how I could go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

along with the options in this answer,
[Google table Chart : how do I change the row background color based on a value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36949638/5090771),

you can set properties on the data table cell.
the table chart will accept cell properties for both `style` and `className`

---

when using object notation to load the data, use the `p:` key to set properties.

```
{v: 'Web', f: null, p: {style: 'background-color: cyan;'}}
```

where `v:` = value, `f:` = formatted value, & `p:` = cell properties

---

to set the properties after the data has been loaded,
you can use any of the following methods.

1) `setCell(rowIndex, columnIndex, value, formattedValue, properties)`

when using `setCell`, properties is the 5th argument, pass an object with the properties you want to set, e.g.

```
data.setCell(0, 0, 'Shoes', null, {style: 'background-color: yellow;'});
```

2) `setProperty(rowIndex, columnIndex, name, value)`

when using `setProperty`, pass the name and value of the property you want to set, e.g.

```
data.setProperty(1, 0, 'style', 'background-color: lime;');
```

3) `setProperties(rowIndex, columnIndex, properties)`

when using `setProperties`, pass an object with the properties you want to set, e.g.

```
data.setProperties(2, 1, {style: 'background-color: magenta;'});
```

---

see following working snippet for examples...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['table']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Department');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Revenues');
  data.addRows([
    ['Shoes', 10700],
    ['Sports', -15400],
    ['Toys', 12500],
    ['Electronics', -2100],
    ['Food', 22600],
    ['Art', 1100],
    [
      // add style property
      {v: 'Web', p: {style: 'background-color: cyan;'}},
      {v: 9999, p: {style: 'background-color: cyan;'}}
    ]
  ]);
  
  // use setCell(rowIndex, columnIndex [, value [, formattedValue [, properties]]])
  data.setCell(0, 0, 'Shoes', null, {style: 'background-color: yellow;'});

  // use setProperty(rowIndex, columnIndex, name, value)
  data.setProperty(1, 0, 'style', 'background-color: lime;');

  // use setProperties(rowIndex, columnIndex, properties)
  data.setProperties(2, 1, {style: 'background-color: magenta;'});

  // use a css className instead of style
  data.setProperty(3, 0, 'className', 'customCell');

  var container = document.getElementById('table_div');
  var table = new google.visualization.Table(container);
  
  table.draw(data, {
    allowHtml: true
  });
});
```

```css
.customCell {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, using the object notation p property was exactly what I needed. I can manually run through all the cells during the row generation, and apply different values for p depending on if certain conditions are met.